# Essentialization of hyperplane arrangement

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, affine-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

I have started reading the following [lecture notes](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/sp06stanley.pdf) on hyperplane arrangements and I am having some trouble with the essentialization of an arrangement explained at the start of the first lecture.

A set of affine hyperplanes $\mathcal{A} = \{H_1, \ldots, H_m\}$ in a vector space $V = K^n$, for some field $K$, is called *essential* if the dimension of the space spanned by the normals of the hyperplanes is equal to $n$, the dimension of $V$. If $K$ happens to be $\mathbb{R}$ we can let $X$ be the space spanned by the normals and consider the set of hyperplanes $\{X \cap H_1, \ldots, X \cap H_m\}$ of $X$. This is essential by definition of $X$ and the original set $\mathcal{A}$ can be recovered because $(X \cap H_i) + X^\perp = H_i$. So in this case this gives an "equivalent" set of hyperplanes which is essential, and is thus called the essentialization of $\mathcal{A}$.

This part was ok for me but the author also describes how to essentialize for a general field $K$, and that's where I cannot quite follow.
The subspace $X$ is defined as before, but now we choose a complement $Y$ for it in $V$ and then take $$ W = Y^\perp = \{ v \in V : v \cdot y = 0 \; \forall y \in Y \}. $$
After that we can proceed as before with $W$ in place of $X$, that is, take the hyperplanes $\{W \cap H_1, \ldots, W \cap H_m\}$. These define an "equivalent" set of hyperplanes which is essential.

This general case is more obscure for me and I cannot quite see why (1) we obtain an essential set of hyperplanes and (2) how one can "reverse" the construction to get $\mathcal{A}$ back.

It would help me if someone could provide a clear explanation/proof for these facts, or even give me a series of simpler steps I can prove to get to those statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point is $codim_{W}(H\cap W)=1$. That is to say, the $rank$ of $\left\{W \cap H_{1}, \ldots, W \cap H_{m}\right\}$ is same to $rank(\mathcal{A})$ and we can take care of a lower dimension version on $W$ correspond to intersecting hyperplanes. If we want to recover the original problem, we need to add $X^{\perp}$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1386737)

Comment: If you give a perfect answer, I will delete it.